# Notification about comments

Tags: support, notifications

Is there a way to receive notification of comments on the main questions page?

(i) I do not want e-mail notification, my inbox is busy enough!

(ii) I would prefer not to have to keep clicking on the "Reputation" link to check for the *possibility* that someone might have a query.

Comment: Doesn't the StackExchange logo on the top left work for you? It is not entirely reliable but most of the time someone left a comment for me I see a red bullet (conatining the number of messages I have on the top left). If you leave a reply to this comment I'll make a screen shot and post it, so you can see how it looks for me.

Comment: [Here's a picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qowk.png). The white $1$ in the red bullet on the top left shows that I received one comment notification.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you, I was unaware of it!  There is a slight complication, in that I have difficulty noticing red (blue would be useful).  But in principle, and, with some effort, probably in practice, your comment solves my problem.

Comment: I suggest that you make this a feature request. Accessibility should be one of the highest priorities of such a site and red may indeed be problematic for many enough. Unfortunately, on the usual sister sites I couldn't find anything allowing you to customize colors. However, here are two links for you that you may want to bookmark for easier accessibility of your inbox: 1. [direct link to your responses tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312?tab=responses) and 2. [raw inbox](http://math.stackexchange.com/inbox).

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, that too will help.

Comment: Another color blind? Hooray. I am not alone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, click the Stack Exchange logo in the upper left. It will show the number of pending messages specifically to you (answers, comments, etc) in a circle.

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/global-inbox-notify.png))</sub>

See details at

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/